# How can I write operational results to remote database from IBM ODM Rules

Tags: ibm-odm

I know it is not a good practice, but I need to write operational decision results into a remote database at the end of execution of the ruleflow. Does IBM ODM 8.7 provides any mechanism to achieve that ? Any workaround ? Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

ODM has a module called Decision Warehouse that does exactly this. It allows the input and output message to be logged as well as other information such as the rules that fired, or rule tasks that executed.

[Here is the ODM documentation on DW](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.7.1/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.res.managing/topics/con_res_dw_overview.html?lang=en).

Answer (score 0):

Here you should have two problems using this approach:

1. All information available in the Warehouse is 'opened'. This means that if you have (probably will) sensitive information, these will appear as plain text in the Warehouse Console — this maybe is not a feasible solution for some companies.
2. You will probably have a loss of performance for the execution of the ruleset. This can delay your business responses in a critical and productive environment.